# Пароль Linux невозможно изменить

Tags: linux, пароль

Решил проверить можно ли использовать в пароле пользователя стрелки. Можно. Но из-за того что программы с графическим интерфейсом не воспринимают стрелки как символы решил поменять пароль обратно. Но столкнулся с тем что при изменении пароля выдаёт ошибку и пишет, что пароль не изменился.
(passwd: Authentication token manipulation error;
passwd: password unchanged;)
Есть физический доступ к серверу.

Comment: а может стрелки просто были проигнорированы?

Comment: не очень понял, вы пробовали от рута задать пароль пользователю? `passwd username` от рута?

Comment: нет, стрелки не проигнорированы - без них пароль не работает. И от рута тоже пытался

Comment: @JavaJumper, еще раз от рута попробуйте. Он же не требует ввода пароля пользователя

Comment: Так я же говорю, от рута пробовал, мне даёт вводить новый пароль, но он не сохраняется